# Icons are missing for input type number

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

Icons are missing for input type number.

In firefox it is coming but in IE it is not working.

Code :

```
<input type="number" class="input-small tight-form-input ng-valid ng-dirty ng-valid-number ng-touched" placeholder="Auto" empty-to-null="" ng-model="panel.grid.leftMax" ng-change="render()" ng-model-onblur="">
```

[image]

Please see the screenshot..

Please help!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number input is not supported in IE <= 9.

It is partially supported in IE 10 & 11 but without the "icons"

From [caniuse.com](http://caniuse.com/#feat=input-number) relating to IE 10 & 11:

> UI widget does not include increment/decrement buttons.